# How do I properly use useSelector + createSelector (from 'reselect') in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using reselect lib in my React project. Here is a code:

```
const App = () => {

  // const { tickets, isFetching, error } = useSelector(({ tickets }) => tickets)   // <- this works good

  const { sorterTabs, selected } = useSelector(({ sorter }) => sorter)
  const { isFetching } = useSelector(({ tickets }) => tickets)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const tickets = useSelector(sorterSelector)   // <- this doesn't work good     

  const handleSorterClick = ({ target }) => {
    dispatch(getSelectedSorter(target.getAttribute('name')))
  }

  const renderedTickets = tickets.map((ticket) => {   // <- problem: I have undefined here because selector returns undefined
    const src = `http://pics.avs.io/99/36/${ticket.carrier}.png`
    return (
      <Ticket
        key={ticket.price + ticket.segments[0].duration}
        ticket={ticket}
        price={ticket.price}
        src={src}
        segment={ticket.segments}
      />
    )
  }).slice(0,5)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData())
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <div className="content">
        <Filter />
        <div className="content__item">
          <div className="content__item__sorting">
            <Sorter
              sorterTabs={sorterTabs}
              selected={selected}
              handleSorterClick={handleSorterClick}
            />
          </div>
          {isFetching 
            ? 
              <img src={preloader} alt="preloader" />
            : 
              <div className="content__item__tickets">
                {renderedTickets}
              </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Code for selector:

```
const allTickets = state => state.tickets.tickets  // <- this gets undefined 
const selected = state => state.sorter.selected

export const sorterSelector = createSelector(
  [allTickets, selected],
  (tickets, selec) => {
    if (selec === "Самый дешевый") {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.price - b.price
      })
    } else {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => {
        return (a.segments[0].duration + a.segments[1].duration) - (b.segments[0].duration + b.segments[1].duration)
      })
    }
  }
)
```

As I mentioned in the App's code, first commented line (where I destructure the object) works good: I'm fetching tickets from the server, put them in redux state, get them in App's component and render them.

But if I create selector by `createSelector` function from 'reselect' lib and put it in `useSelector` function like I mentioned in the code `const tickets = useSelector(sorterSelector)`, I got mistake: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Tickets are not returned from the state, but state is empty. That means that `fetchData` function didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here? How to use it properly?

UPD: this doesn't work too `const tickets = useSelector((state) => sorterSelector(state))`

Comment: I don't have experience about reselect. But I checked the document. `createSelector` prototype seems like (func1, func2, ..., mapFunc) not ([...funcitions], mapper).

Comment: @hellikiam, have already tried, didn't work

Comment: @rgdzv I updated answer, state.tickets is not an array but has isFetching and error so you can't just sort something that is not available (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is proper return in selector:

```
export const sorterSelector = createSelector(
  [allTickets, selected],
  (tickets, selec) => {
    if (tickets.isFetching || tickets.error) {
      return []
    }
    if (selec === "Самый дешевый") {
      return [...tickets.tickets].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
    } else {
      return [...tickets.tickets].sort((a, b) => (a.segments[0].duration + a.segments[1].duration) - (b.segments[0].duration + b.segments[1].duration))
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
const allTickets = state => state.tickets
```

[Here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) is some info about how I use selectors.

Note that your selector is mutating state because Array.prototype.sort will mutate arrays. I noticed that state.tickets may be loading or have an error so state.tickets.tickets will not be set when it is still loading, that means you can't sort it because there is nothing there.

```
export const sorterSelector = createSelector(
  [allTickets, selected],
  (tickets, selec) => {
    if(tickets.isFetcing || tickets.error) {
      return [];
    }
    if (selec === "Самый дешевый") {
      //sort a shallow copy
      [...tickets.tickets].sort((a, b) => {
        return a.price - b.price
      })
    } else {
      //sort a  shallow copy
      [...tickets.tickets].sort((a, b) => {
        return (a.segments[0].duration + a.segments[1].duration) - (b.segments[0].duration + b.segments[1].duration)
      })
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: @hm...did everything as you explained, but didn't work. Same mistake (`cannot read map of undefined`)

Comment: logic is good, but I don't see that `fetchData` is even launched in that case. I have no idea why